# How to access the email of a Facebook user?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication

I have implemented Facebook authentication on my website. I have asked for user permissions to access their email address. I am testing the application right now and have granted permissions through my profile. I would like to know how can I access the email of the logged in Facebook user?

**NOTE: I have already asked for the permission to access the email and have granted them from my profile for testing purpose.**

Thanks,
Anurag

Comment: You should accept some more answers. < 40% acceptance with 23 questions is pretty low.

Comment: Is it bad that my knee-jerk reaction to the question title was ***"redirect them to a page that looks like facebook and display a login form"***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$facebook->api('/me?fields=email');
//and result should be something like
Array
(
    [email] => someemail
    [id] => someid_of_user
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just grab the object on graph: https://graph.facebook.com/{user id here}

All users have an "email" attribute.

Read [the docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) on users.